# Matrix routing failure with no error message

Tags: here-api

I have one failed route when calculating a route matrix, but there is no error message to indicate what the failure is.

What's more strange is that when calculating the route that failed separately in one call (i.e with one start and one destination), it succeeds.

So the failure only happens with that combination of routes.

Any idea about why this might be happening?
Is there a way know more about a route failure?

To demonstrate this, here are two requests where the same route is failing in one and succeeding in another:

**One start, two destinations including the problematic one:**

Starts: `45.518000,-73.582200`
Destinations: `48.465500,-123.360700` (**fails**), `43.442600,-79.676900`

`https://matrix.route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json?app_id=SECRET&app_code=SECRET&start0=geo!45.518000,-73.582200&destination0=geo!48.465500,-123.360700&destination1=geo!43.442600,-79.676900&mode=balanced;car;traffic:disabled`

**Response:**

```
{
  "response": {
    "metaInfo": {
      "timestamp": "2018-12-28T16:00:57Z",
      "mapVersion": "8.30.91.157",
      "moduleVersion": "7.2.201850-1162",
      "interfaceVersion": "2.6.34",
      "availableMapVersion": [
        "8.30.91.157"
      ]
    },
    "matrixEntry": [
      {
        "startIndex": 0,
        "destinationIndex": 0,
        "status": "failed"
      },
      {
        "startIndex": 0,
        "destinationIndex": 1,
        "summary": {
          "distance": 583876,
          "travelTime": 22757,
          "costFactor": 26806,
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**One start, one dest which is the problematic one:**

And it succeeds.

`https://matrix.route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json?app_id=SECRET&app_code=SECRET&start0=geo!45.518000,-73.582200&destination0=geo!48.465500,-123.360700&mode=balanced;car;traffic:disabled`

**Response:**

```
{
  "response": {
    "metaInfo": {
      "timestamp": "2018-12-28T16:09:26Z",
      "mapVersion": "8.30.91.157",
      "moduleVersion": "7.2.201850-1162",
      "interfaceVersion": "2.6.34",
      "availableMapVersion": [
        "8.30.91.157"
      ]
    },
    "matrixEntry": [
      {
        "startIndex": 0,
        "destinationIndex": 0,
        "summary": {
          "distance": 4709849,
          "travelTime": 196163,
          "costFactor": 225708,
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It is worth noting that the problematic route is different from the others in that the destination is very far apart from the other destinations.

Answer (score 0):

The route fail may occur if the area covered by waypoints is very large as the API may tradeoff canceling a request to keep the response time within certain limits. With the latest update with the API the response is better now and the shared waypoints are returning results.

Comment: That's what I had noticed. I actually resorted to separating my requests into chunks of nearby locations, which decreased the error rate.
So with the latest update, this issue does not occur anymore at all? Should I still separate my request into chunks?

Comment: Separating into chunks is always recommended and should be continued. If your matrices cover a larger number of waypoints you could experiment with the Large Matrix routing API , however note this is a new API and is not covered under the Freemium Plan.